# How to create transaction in Spring Boot aop @Around function?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, aop

I want to implement an authorization method by using Spring Boot AOP. The original idea is, if the return object return from the REST calls didn't pass the authorization check, it will throw a unauthorized exception.

I'm doing it like this:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthAspect {
  @Around("AllRestExecPoint()")
  public Object auth(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    Object returnObject = point.proceed();
    if (!checkAuthorization(returnObject)) {
      throw new UnauthException();
    }
    return returnObject;
  }
}
```

However, the problem is, if this REST service will execute some INSERT or UPDATE to my DB, it will commit before my authorization checks. Therefore, the `UnauthException` will be thrown but the transaction is still committed.

The first try I want to manually create transaction before the `proceed()` call and commit it before return, but it failed.

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthAspect {
  private final EntityManager em;

  @Autowired
  public AuthAspect(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
  }

  @Around("AllRestExecPoint()")
  public Object auth(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Object returnObject = point.proceed();
    if (!checkAuthorization(returnObject)) {
      throw new UnauthException();
    }

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return returnObject;
  }
}
```

It will cause the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead`.

I searched on the internet and some answers need to modify `web.xml` file, but I don't want to use xml to do the configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from your tags you are using Spring Boot. Spring Boot provides a pre-configured [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) which you can use if you manually want to control transactions.

Instead of the `EntityManger` inject this into your aspect and wrap your code in it.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthAspect {
  private final TransactionTemplate tx;

  public AuthAspect(TransactionTemplate tx) {
    this.tx = tx;
  }

  @Around("AllRestExecPoint()")
  public Object auth(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    return tx.execute(ts -> this.executeAuth(pjp));   
  }

  private Object executeAuth(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    Object returnObject;
    try {
      returnObject  = pjp.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      throw new AopInvocationException(t.getMessage(), t);
    }
    if (!checkAuthorization(returnObject)) {
      throw new UnauthException();
    }
    return returnObject;
  }
}
```

This will execute the logic inside a transaction. I moved the actual logic to a method so that the lambda can be a single method instead of code block. (Personal preference/best practice).

Comment: I can't throw Throwable from the lambda expression, Is there any method I can use .this approach and still throwing Throwable? Because I have a ```GlobalExceptionHandler``` to catch Exception and return error code to the client.

Comment: Doh my mistake (it still is 07:00 around here :) ). You can always wrap the throwable in an `RuntimeException`, by placing a `try/catch` into the `executeAuth` method. This way you can remove the `throws Throwable`. Modified the code as mentioned, I assumed that `UnauthException` is actually a `RuntimeException` as well!

Comment: After looking at your comments, you might not need to start your own transaction. Instead make sure that your aspect always runs AFTER the transactional aspect. That way you are always inside a transaction and you don't need to mess around with transactions yourself. Problem is you are now making your web layer transactional which generally is a bad idea. Could you rewrite the point cut to match on the service rather then the rest endpoints?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The problem is the transaction may not be created in the direct callee. Our aspect only intercept all REST services, but the transaction may be created in deeper service call, which I think I can't set the order to make the AOP runs in the transaction which callee uses. Could I ask why making web layer transactional is generally a bad idea? What is the risk of this approach?

Comment: Do you want to fail the transaction if for some reason the redirect or something web related fails?

Comment: My thought is if any error occurs, our DataSource should be unmodified. For example if user want to update some critical data and Exception is thrown, those data should not be saved.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do and this solution works (kind of) but you loose the ability to manage transactions through `@Transactional` as those will be largely ignored because there is already an ongoing transaction.

Comment: I see. I think it's a trade-off of this approach. I'll make aware of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking your code, you need to update a couple of things:

1. If you want to call EntityManager,  you need to call by following way, using in persistence context.

   ```
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;
   ```
2. In order to do queries or something in transaction context, you just need to add Transactional tag on method header and don't call getTransaction from EntityManager.

   ```
   @Transactional
   @Around("AllRestExecPoint()")
   public Object auth(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        em.createNativeQuery(query) //If it is necessary. 
        ...
   }
   ```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. No matter which of ```org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional``` and ```javax.transaction.Transactional``` used, it still didn't create transaction in ```auth()``` method.

Comment: The first one Transactional of spring, if you create some query in the interception method Auth, that query will be in transaction context.. @Nier,

Comment: I didn't create query in my ```auth()``` function, ```@Transactional``` is declared in some services which ```point.proceed()``` may or may not call. I want to create a transaction so transaction in service will use existed one instead of create new one, so I can roll back all updates if security authentication failed.